# Simple transformation in Dask data frame produces unexpected result

Tags: python, dask

I have what looks to be a simple task: Compute the grouped cumulative ('running') minimum of Dask DataFrame column.

My data frame looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100000, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"))
df["id"] = np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 100000)
df["col"] = np.random.choice(["X", "Y", "Z", "G"], 100000)

df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
df = df.set_index("id")
```

Now I want to add a column to `df` that contains the cumulative ("running") minimum of column `A` grouped by column `col`. I've tried the following:

```py
res = df.groupby("col")["A"].transform("cummin", meta = ("a", "f8")).compute()
```

but when I compare the result to what it should be:

```py
res
df.compute()
```

the two differ in that `res` seems misaligned. Would anyone know how to fix this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the ordering is not that surprising, when looking what your code does.

It helps to start with a smaller example to actually see what your are doing.

Your ordering depends on the ordering in the groups of your `groupby`...

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"))
df["id"] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]  # unique ids...
df["col"] = np.random.choice(["X", "Y"], 10)

df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

`groupby` leads to the following indices (`df.compute().groupby("col").groups`):

**{'X': [0, 2, 5, 7, 9], 'Y': [1, 3, 4, 6, 8]}**

The following three commands and the resulting indices (and images) should clear the behaviour. **Please note the order of indexing and on which part of the DataFrame the Groupby!**

```py
res = df[["A", "col"]].groupby("col").transform("cummin", meta={'A': 'f8'}).compute()  # AX

res2 = df.groupby("col")["A"].transform("cummin", meta = ("A-Question", "f8")).compute()  # your solution -> AQ

res3 = df[["A", "col"]].groupby("col")['A'].transform("cummin", meta= ("A2", "f8"))  # AY
```

[image]

I am not sure why `AQ` and `AY` are different, but maybe the indices are different due to the partitions of the dask dataframe (...?)